# Implementing Neural Network using CUDA

Tags: cuda, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, gpgpu

I am trying to create a Neural Network using CUDA:

My kernel looks like :

```
__global__ void feedForward(float *input, float *output, float **weight) {

//Here the threadId uniquely identifies weight in a neuron
int weightIndex = threadIdx.x;

//Here the blockId uniquely identifies a neuron
int neuronIndex = blockIdx.x;

if(neuronIndex<NO_OF_NEURONS && weightIndex<NO_OF_WEIGHTS)
output[neuronIndex] += weight[neuronIndex][weightIndex]
        * input[weightIndex];
}
```

While copying the output back to host, I'm getting an error

Error unspecified launch failure at line xx

At line xx :

```
CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaMemcpy(h_output, d_Output, output_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Is it because of how I'm using both the block index as well as thread index to reference the weight matrix. 
Or does the problem lie elsewhere ?

I'm allcoating the weight matrix as follows:

```
cudaMallocPitch((void**)&d_Weight, &pitch_W,input_size,NO_OF_NEURONS);
```

My kernel call is:

```
feedForward<<<NO_OF_NEURONS,NO_OF_WEIGHTS>>>(d_Input,d_Output,d_Weight);
```

After that i call:
cudaThreadSynchronize();

I am new to programming with CUDA.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How is `weight` allocated? Show the code where you are allocating memories and also the kernel launch.

Comment: Can you should how you are allocating the weight array?

Comment: unspecified launch failure usually means your kernel failed to do something. Check for an error before the copy. I bet you are not copying weights in the correct manner.

Comment: 1). How do you launch your kernel? 2). You have an error in writing to output array. All threads within a block is concurently writing data to a single memory cell. You may replace this part of code with reduction in shared memory and single global memory write.

Comment: if you comment out everything that reads or writes to the global memory and it runs without giving an error, that means segmentation fault, -> your indexing is wrong. Also are you sure that you have not transposed neuronIndex with weightIndex?  `weight[neuronIndex][weightIndex]` should be ` weight[weightIndex][neuronIndex]` ? as it is usally that the smaller index of a 2d array is the latter index.

Comment: Can you provide the host code before and after initialization of kernel?

Comment: As requested I have added the code for memory allocation and kernel launch.

Comment: @OlegTitov Could you please elaborate a bit? How do i replace it with "Reduction in shared memory and single global memory write"?

Comment: Now that I see the snippets - Google and Facebook are underrated!

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in output code. Though it won't produce the error described, it will produce incorrect results.

```
int neuronIndex = blockIdx.x;

if(neuronIndex<NO_OF_NEURONS && weightIndex<NO_OF_WEIGHTS)
output[neuronIndex] += weight[neuronIndex][weightIndex] * input[weightIndex];
```

We can see that all threads in single block are writing concurrently into one memory cell. So udefined results are expected. To avoid this I suggest reduce all values within a block in shared memory and perform a single write to global memory. Something like this:

```
__global__ void feedForward(float *input, float *output, float **weight) {

  int weightIndex = threadIdx.x;
  int neuronIndex = blockIdx.x;
  __shared__ float out_reduce[NO_OF_WEIGHTS];

  out_reduce[weightIndex] = 
     (weightIndex<NO_OF_WEIGHTS && neuronIndex<NO_OF_NEURONS) ? 
       weight[neuronIndex][weightIndex] * input[weightIndex]
       : 0.0;
  __syncthreads();

  for (int s = NO_OF_WEIGHTS; s > 0 ; s >>= 1)
  {
    if (weightIndex < s) out_reduce[weightIndex] += out_reduce[weightIndex + s];
    __syncthreads();
  }

  if (weightIndex == 0) output[neuronIndex] += out_reduce[weightIndex]; 
}
```

It turned out that I had to rewrite half of you small kernel to help with reduction code...

Comment: Thanmks for letting me know about reduction. But it did not solve the problem. Any one got any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

I build a very simple MLP network using CUDA. You can find my code over here if it may interest you: https://github.com/PirosB3/CudaNeuralNetworks/
For any questions, just shoot!

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

You're using cudaMallocPitch, but don't show how the variables are initialized; I'd be willing to bet this is where your error stems from. cudaMallocPitch is rather tricky; the 3rd parameter should be in bytes, while the 4th parameter is not. i.e.

```
int width = 64, height = 64;
float* devPtr;
size_t pitch;
cudaMallocPitch(&device_Ptr, &pitch, width * sizeof(float), height);
```

Is your variable input_size in bytes? If not, then you might be allocating too little memory (i.e. you'll think you're requesting 64 elements, but instead you'll be getting 64 bytes), and as such you'll be accessing memory out of range in your kernel. In my experience, an "unspecified launch failure" error usually means I have a segfault

Comment: 'input_size' is in bytes.
It is initialialized as:

    int input_size = NO_OF_WEIGHTS * sizeof(float);

Comment: Well I guess we can rule that out then. Do you use the pitch value anywhere?

Comment: not yet... But I will need it later to copy the weights from device to host.